# How to test 404 json response on ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit

Considering that in my Zend Framework module I'm able to access via browser or REST. When I got a 404 via REST, this is the content:

`{"httpStatus":404,"title":"Not Found"}`

So how do I test this response using PHPUnit?

I have already a test for another route that is working:

```
public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
{      
    $this->dispatch('/ws/dashboard');
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);

    $this->assertModuleName('Ws');
    $this->assertControllerName('Ws\Controller\Dashboard');
    $this->assertControllerClass('DashboardController');
    $this->assertMatchedRouteName('application/ws');
}
```

But I don't know how to do this other case.

```
public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
{
    $this->dispatch('/ws/asd');
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(404); // this is OK
    // but how check the json response?
}
```

Also, if I do this `$response = $this->getResponse();` I got the entire HTML 404 html file, which is not what I want.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to test. Testing the 404 response works ok i.e. `$this->assertResponseStatusCode(404);`. You can test against the Json response by using `$this->getResponse()`, but you said that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check to ensure that the controller is actually returning a JSON response.

Also, your Accept header for the AJAX request should specify application/json.